# How to force audio output?

Tags: bluetooth, audio, calls, bluetooth-audio

I'm looking for a way to force audio output when i call someone :

I have a galaxy S7 connected to a bluetooth earphone and a bluetooth smartswatch.
When I call someone with the smartswatch, the output is the smartswatch, but i'd like to have the sound automatically on the earphone without having to switch it on the phone.

Any solution ?